# How does the Cassandra distribute data?

Tags: cassandra

I cannot find a detailed document on this anywhere, however, that being said, if anyone has an answer to my question, I would be extremely grateful.

In regards to Cassandra's standard node architecture, you are required as the administrator to divide the hash range by the number of nodes in the cluster, thus you have your tokens.

That being said, vnode tokens are generated automagically, and architecturally, I am curious as to how the system maintains these tokens.

To further specify my question for virtual nodes does the cluster re-evaluate tokens for all nodes just because a new host has been added?

To further this thought process, I am inclined to believe that it doesn't, as that would be a very expensive operation moving around any data that would then be in the wrong node due to the recalculation.  Unfortunately, I cannot find out what happens...

Also, if two nodes can hold the same token, doesn't that break the architecture, or at very least doesn't it make designating replication factor almost pointless, as it should be written to all nodes that have the specified vtoken/token?

How is a vnode chosen for a particular token are the tokens assigned serially or randomly?

Lots of difficult questions, however I am counting on any Cassandra hanging around.

Thank you,

Scott

Answer (score 2):

I initially just wanted to point at this as a comment, but my rep is too low. So excuse me if this is not a fully fledged answer. (Anyone feel free to edit or hint in comments)

Looking at [the documentation at datastax](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeVnodesUsing_c.html) it appears that data will be evently divided by nodes, depending on the "automagical" tokens. From my understanding it's simple as that a new vnode with new tokens just takes an even portion of each node, like all the other nodes already do. Hell, this is even what the doc says basically word by word:

> Rebalancing a cluster is no longer necessary when adding or removing nodes. When a node joins the cluster, it assumes responsibility for an even portion of data from the other nodes in the cluster. If a node fails, the load is spread evenly across other nodes in the cluster.

And to address your question:

> To further specify my question for virtual nodes **does the cluster re-evaluate tokens for all nodes just because a new host has been added?**

Sort of. The new node itself takes some partitions (evenly) from all other nodes. If you remove a node every other node will rebalance its partitions from the other nodes, making up for the lost node.

Comment: So, when they are speaking of rebalancing the cluster they are refering to the tokens on each node?... thats no longer nessessary?  Additionally, nodes default to 255vnodes does this mean the cluster is 255 partitions? Or 255*the number of nodes?  What about your low powered nodes?128vnodes which partitions do they get.

Comment: From my understanding that's the whole point of vnodes, yes.

Comment: Sorry commented a bit early.  I edited my response.

Comment: Check out the [graphical representation in the documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeDistribute_c.html). At the top there is also a hint about token generation (which is not needed).

Comment: Generation is not manually required from my understanding... as such i would assume that they are automatically generated.  Otherwise how could the key hash be matched to a physical node.  The total number of vnodes can be set of couse, however what is the max number of vnodes in the hash range? 255*nodes? Or is it based on the node with the largest vnode setting?